# How do I check how much power my laptop is drawing?

Tags: power-management

How can I check how much power my laptop is pulling at any given time?

Comment: Might want to check Lesswatts http://www.lesswatts.org/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install and run `powertop`:

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
sudo powertop
```

Comment: Don't install this if you're looking for power measurements.  They appear to be event frequency and duty cycle measurements.  I don't see why this was accepted as an answer.

Comment: @broiyan, because it *also* shows how much power you are using and how long the battery will last.

Answer (score 1):

`powertop` offers wattage starting from 2.0 version.

the `acpi` command also offers power consumption.